# Stuck on Windows

Tags: virtualbox, windows

It has gotten a bit of frustrating that I keep going back to Windows because of academic reasons; there are some softwares like PSpice and Microwind, MATLAB and others that's required for certain courses. There might be alternatives, but surely that can't be enough when my whole course layout is based on Winodows softwares and everyone's using Winodws. Also, there's Microsoft Office, which of course stands alone; and when I think or worry about taking a job, I have to learn office...

My PC has 8GB of RAM, with Intel core-i5 4460 3.20 GHz processor, and integrated Intel HD Graphics-4600. Is there someone with almost the same kind of specs running Windows in VirtualBox inside Ubuntu, for academic or professional purposes? Some apps might work with Wine, but those might be very old versions... I'm wondering if my specs will be enough to meet my needs with a Windows virtual machine operating inside Ubuntu...

Sorry if question seems somewhat lame or stupid, but I'm really bugged over this!!

Comment: Not sure about the VM, but there are a few nice alternatives for two of those. [MATLAB has a Linux version](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103682). LibreOffice or Google Docs/Sheets or Office 365 can handle Microsoft Office files (especially Office 365, since it's made by Microsoft).

Comment: "I'm wondering if my specs will be enough to meet my needs with a Windows virtual machine operating inside Ubuntu..." Yes. Well, I can and use it for gaming with only 4Gb. This actually is something you will need to try yourself and see how it goes. Maybe you can live with it being a bit slower. Or maybe you can allocate close to 8Gb to the VM (and not use Ubuntu while using the VM). Pretty much the answer is: try it and see for yourself ;-)